# What kind of crimp part is used for stress relief on dipole?

Tags: antenna-construction, wire-antenna, dipole

I like the way that the person provides stress relief for the dipole antenna wire in the following image.  However, I cannot figure out what kind of crimp "device" they are using for making the loop.  Butt connector?  Splice?  ???  Can someone clue me in?  What kind of crimp tool and die is required?

[image]

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: that would look like an aluminium ferrule, crimped with either specific pliers, or just any old plier and patience in two places.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It goes by several names,

- ferrule
- compression sleeve
- swage sleeve
- cable crimp

but the key fact is that it is not an electronics part, but a mechanical one. They are sold for use with **wire rope**, precisely for this use: making an end loop that can withstand lots of tension and vibration. You might have also seen them on wire rope bracing outdoor structures or suspending things from a ceiling.

Also, the tool may be called a “swaging” tool rather than a “crimping” tool.

Look for “wire rope” at your hardware store, and you should be able to find them.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response, Kevin!  When I saw "wire rope", the light went on in my head.  I found some aluminum ferrules at home depot and was able to assemble the dipole today!

Answer (score 1):

There are aluminum electric fence wire ferrules. They do make a tool to make the crimp. 73'

AI5DH

[image]